# What dependencies need to be added for jasperreport 5.0.1?

Tags: jasper-reports

I **upgraded jasper report version** from **4.5.0 to 5.1.0**. When i install my plugin it throws error like some dependency missing. I would like to configure JasperReports 5.1.0 with Maven.

```
Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-2:compile-reports failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js2
```

I am having two queries.

1) I want to know **what are all the dependency** that I have **to add in pom** to use jasper report 5.1.0.

2) I am using below plugin **to compile my jrxml files to jasper files**. I see that issue in this plugin. What could be the issue in this plugin. Should I have to add any mirror ?

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-beta-2</version>
```

My complete pom is, There may be extra dependencies other that jasper report, I am using it for my internal purpose.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>report-test-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1.1001-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>report-test-plugin</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-artifact.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact-manager</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-artifact-manager.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-model.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${plexus-utils.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
            <version>${wagon-provider-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>${dom4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
            <version>${jmock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-configuration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  itext -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-xtra</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
            <version>R8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlcleaner</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.9</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1</version>
              <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                   </executions>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
<!--                             define where is your jrxml file -->
                            <sourceDirectory>src\\main\\resources</sourceDirectory>
                            <sourceFileExt>.jrxml</sourceFileExt>
                            <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler</compiler>
<!--                             define where is the jasper file will be generated -->
                            <outputDirectory>src\\main\\resources</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
<!--                     Note this must be repeated here to pick up correct xml validation -->

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.16</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For anyone having similar issues when using the JasperReports 5.x maven dependencies:

The jasper guys run a [public maven repository](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/2594-0#comment-800972) where they publish bug fixes to their third party dependencies. These fixed versions are not always present in the public maven repo. So when you have problems with dependencies try to add the repository http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the solution was adding

```
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>
```

This way it was not looking for the .js2 version and could resolve the dependency.