# Maven fails to pull dependencies on travis-ci: Connection timed out

Tags: java, maven, testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci

After setting up my project to use travis, I've been experiencing one particular issue with it: On totally random occasions, the build fails due to maven not being able to pull all dependencies.

The problem seemed to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17656171/2713162), since the main dependency not getting pulled was jasperreports. But the problem persisted even after I added their repo to my pom file (and it seems like bad practice to me, correct me if I'm wrong).

For example, see [this build](https://travis-ci.org/oskopek/carcv/builds/14284632). It failed, but had no reason to, because the commit before it passed, and the change shouldn't have caused a failure for sure. It even failed *differently*  (with different dependencies that failed to be downloaded).

I also noticed that the test failures don't follow any patterns: sometimes the build passes, sometimes it fails only on one of the JDKs and very often it fails on both of them.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how to fix this? Is it a problem on my side (configuration of maven/travis) or a server-side (networking?) problem?

Here is an excerpt of the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project carcv-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.carcv.webapp:carcv-webapp:war:1.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT:
 Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:5.2.0 -> com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js2:
 Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js2:
 Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js2 from/to jasperreports (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2):
 Connection to http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net refused: Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been a networking, or rather, load management issue. Maven doesn't seem to like how the jasperreports repository responds - for the last few builds, it would just hang and the build would timeout ([see here](https://travis-ci.org/oskopek/carcv/jobs/17796542)).

There are multiple ways you could solve this:

1. Download a version of the jasperreports library with all dependencies, put it in a `lib/` folder in your code base and have maven load them from there
2. Have Travis download and extract an archive of the jasperreports library with all it's dependencies at test-time (in order not to pollute your code base)
3. Mirror the jasperreports maven repository on your own server

I liked the third approach best, so I decided to create a little bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DIR=$HOME/temp_jasper/
export TARGET=$HOME/jasper-mirror/
mkdir $DIR
cd $DIR
wget -r --page-requisites --convert-links --no-parent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/
mkdir $TARGET
mv $DIR/jasperreports.sourceforge.net/* $TARGET
```

Schedule a cron job to do the work daily/weekly/monthly/manually (whatever you want).

I created an OpenShift app using the [httpd cartridge created by Stefano Zanella](https://github.com/stefanozanella/openshift-cartridge-httpd), ran the script locally to get the files, added them to the root directory of the git repository, and pushed. You can see the repository files live [here](http://httpd-oskopek.rhcloud.com/maven2/).

After that, change the jasperreports repository in your pom file:

```
    <repositories>
        <!-- Own mirror of jasperreport's repository 
             Original: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/ -->
        <repository>
            <id>jasperreports-mirror</id>
            <url>http://httpd-oskopek.rhcloud.com/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Commit, push and see the build turn green.